# How to cancel take profit order when stop loss order is activated using python binance

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, binance

How to cancel take profit order when stop loss order is activated using python binance?

In future trading, I have opened a long position and placed take profit order as well as stop loss order.

**I have used the following code to open long position:**

'''client.futures_create_order(symbol=BTCBUSD, side='BUY', type='MARKET', positionSide='LONG', quantity=0.002054)'''

the above code worked properly.

my issue is, when one of the orders has been triggered and filled, the position is closed. but, the other order remained opened in the list of open orders.

In my case, the stop loss order is activated and the position has been already closed consequently. But the take profit order keeps opened.

my question is, How to cancel the take profit order once stop loss order is filled. because no longer position is being opened.

**I have used the following code to place a take profit order and stop loss order (TP/SL):**

i.e. at the time of opening position, the price of BTCBUSD=48662.40

'''
client.futures_create_order(symbol=ticker, side='SELL', type='TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', positionSide='LONG', stopPrice=46700, closePosition='true')

client.futures_create_order(symbol=BTCBUSD, side='SELL', type='STOP_MARKET', positionSide='LONG',stopPrice=46660, closePosition='true')
'''